# Пример по xml php

Tags: xml, php

Доброе утро всем! Никогда раньше не работал с xml, прочел уже несколько статей, но не доходит(). Вот как например сделать вот эту задачу:  есть две папки xml(здесь хранится xml файлы) и php(а здесь php), 
допустим нужно соединится с БД, а все данные(пароль, логин и т.д.) хранится в bd.xml, соединяемся с БД через bd.php,  вот как эту задачу выполнить, как с xml взять данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные можно вытягивать вот так:
[Базовое использование SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

[SimpleXML php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: во, хорошие примеры, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - использовать XSL преобразования (см https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php ) . Если выполняете XSL преобразование в среде PHP то там можно даже подключать потоки контента, формируемые PHP скриптами из базы данных. На этом построена одна довольно популярная в России CMS.
Но это самое мощное средство и оно не всегда необходимо.